# pd.groupby then using reset_index() changing my totals

Tags: pandas

Needed:
I needed to get a 5 million row dataset grouped in tidy data format and exported into excel for a couple end users. So I did a groupby using 3 columns and one amount column for the values. Columns with 20 rows below

```
stack_df = pd.DataFrame({'Team' : ['team' + str(i + 1) for i in range(20)],
                         'State': ['state' + str(i + 1) for i in range(20)],
                         'Amount': [i for i in range(20)],
                         'Region' : ['region' + str(i + 1) for i in range(20)]
                            })
```

Process:
To do this I used `groupby...reset_index()`

The below `df1` altered by total Amount Sum, but only for some `'Region's`.

```
df1 = stack_df.groupby(['Team', 'State', 'Region'])['Amount'].sum().reset_index()
```

I then did this to check my numbers:

```
df1.groupby('Team')['Amount'].sum()
```

I would get different amount totals than the `df2 groupby` below that did not have multiple columns in the original `groupby()` function.

```
df2 = stack_df.groupby('Team')['Amount'].sum().reset_index()
```

I used the `groupby` below to see if I just messed up.
Totals are still correct in `df2` when checked using.

```
df2.groupby('Team')['Amount'].sum()
```

[image: Results Snapshot Example]

`df1` amounts above are not correct, but `df2` amounts are.

I am assuming I am not understanding how `reset_index()` actually works, but didn't see anything in the docs or certain parameters that jumped out at me.

Is this user error? Or is my comprehension incorrect?

Comment: Can you please clarify your problem?

Comment: Ok, added more information. Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't change anything. This is a sum, It doesn't matter if you do it in 2 passes

With your sample:

```
df1 = stack_df.groupby(['Team', 'State', 'Region'])['Amount'].sum().reset_index()
df1 = df1.groupby('Team')['Amount'].sum()

df2 = stack_df.groupby('Team')['Amount'].sum().reset_index()
df2 = df2.groupby('Team')['Amount'].sum()
```

Output:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['df1', 'df2'], axis=1)

        df1  df2
Team            
team1     0    0
team10    9    9
team11   10   10
team12   11   11
team13   12   12
team14   13   13
team15   14   14
team16   15   15
team17   16   16
team18   17   17
team19   18   18
team2     1    1
team20   19   19
team3     2    2
team4     3    3
team5     4    4
team6     5    5
team7     6    6
team8     7    7
team9     8    8
```

I don't understand where is the problem but your code seems to be correct.

Comment: Ok, I will double check everything. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere else. Thanks for your help